# Firebase web hosting set to private until ready to make live

Tags: firebase

I would like to use my firebase webapp url `(myproject.firebaseapp.com)` as a sort of test server until I'm ready to deploy my website live, but I don't want others to be able to see it/access it in any way until that time. Is there a way to do this? Some kind of security rules or something..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, you have 2 options:

- [Authentication console](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400802) , [User Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html)
- [Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)

Comment: Hmm the Authentication console looks like what I need. Thanks for the links!